# Animate a menu using display: flex;

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, flexbox

I'd like to animate a menu using `display: flex` with JavaScript (jQuery or vanilla). This doesn't work:

```js
$('#blah').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('#mid').animate({flex:'0 0 20%'});
  return false; 
});
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0; }
#menu { background-color: yellow; display: flex; }
#left {background-color: green; flex: 0 0 200px; }
#mid { background-color: red; flex: 0 0 40%; }
#right {background-color: blue; flex: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="left">left green: 200px</div> 
  <div id="mid">mid red: 40% of browser width</div> 
  <div id="right">right blue: rest</div>
</div>
<div>
<a href="" id="blah">click here to animate mid to 20%!</a>
</div>
```

Animate a menu using CSS `display: flex` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flexBasis` in `animate` function instead of `flex`.

```js
$('#blah').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('#mid').animate({flexBasis:'20%'});
  return false; 
});
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0; }
#menu { background-color: yellow; display: flex; }
#left {background-color: green; flex: 0 0 200px; }
#mid { background-color: red; flex: 0 0 40%; }
#right {background-color: blue; flex: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="left">left green: 200px</div> 
  <div id="mid">mid red: 40% of browser width</div> 
  <div id="right">right blue: rest</div>
</div>
<div>
<a href="" id="blah">click here to animate mid to 20%!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work for you?

```js
$('#blah').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('#mid').css('flex', '0 0 20%');
  return false; 
});
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0; }
#menu { background-color: yellow; display: flex; }
#left {background-color: green; flex: 0 0 200px; }
#mid { background-color: red; flex: 0 0 40%; transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out}
#right {background-color: blue; flex: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="left">left green: 200px</div> 
  <div id="mid">mid red: 40% of browser width</div> 
  <div id="right">right blue: rest</div>
</div>
<div>
<a href="" id="blah">click here to animate mid to 20%!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No sorry, the goal is here to "animate".

Comment: Just add a transition to the css class and it will do what you need it to. I have added it to the snippet above